# Azure Search Multipolygon

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I know that Azure Search supports simple polygon in WKT format. Does it also support MULTI POLYGON. If not, when can we expect this feature to become available.

Also, is there a limit to the number of vertices a polygon can have ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Search doesn't support multipolygons. To represent one, you need to build a filter query that constructs a multipolygon using a combination of polygons, for example, to represent a ring:

```
filter=geo.intersects(location, geography'POLYGON((<coordinates of the external ring>))') and not geo.intersects(location, geography'POLYGON((<coordinates of the internal ring>))')
```

Currently we don't enforce a limit to the number of vertices a polygon can have but this might change in the future API versions.